# Mouse does not work with Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, mouse

I have a Win 7 64-bit Pro desktop that I am trying to run Remote Desktop on to connect to my Windows Home Server 2011 server.  When I connect, my server's desktop is visible and I can see and move my mouse but when I left-click the mouse, nothing happens.  Then if I right-click, the desktop's context menu does display but it's in the bottom-left corner every time I right-click regardless of where I click.  When the context menu displays and I hover the cursor over an item, it doesn't highlight blue like it should.  So basically the mouse just isn't working at all over Remote Desktop.

Everything works fine on the server if I log directly into it with mouse and keyboard.  I should also note that the exact same thing happens if I try to use Remote Desktop to connect from my Win 7 64-bit Home Premium laptop to my Win 7 Pro desktop above.

And finally, if I use Remote Desktop to connect from either my laptop or desktop to my Win XP Pro system at work, everything works perfectly fine. So is it something with connecting to a Win 7 or WHS 2011 system?  Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I should note that the keyboard does work on the remote machine through Remote Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

To me it looks like you have to grant access (on the remote computer) such that the "visitor" (from where you are accessing) can take control.

Comment: It's not an access issue because the keyboard works fine and I'm able to view the remote machine's desktop.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had this program running on the server that reverses the mouse.  This is necessary since I use a trackball turned 180 degrees for better comfort and use Sakasa Mouse to reverse the mouse output.  But I didn't need it on both the server and desktop system.